# AWS Step Function NumericGreaterThan a Parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

In an AWS Step Function, in a Choice step, we want to compare a result from an AWS Lambda function to a threshold given as a parameter using "NumericGreaterThan".

In our example, we compare a calculated from a lambda with a threshold given by the event.

I tried defining my step function in the following way:

```
{
  "StartAt": "Check Enough Data",
  "States": {
    "Check Enough Data": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:REGION:ID:function:FUNCTION:$LATEST",
      "Next": "Validate Count",
      "ResultPath": "$.count"
    },
    "Validate Count": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.count",
          "NumericGreaterThan": "$.threshold",
          "Next": "Succeed State"
        }
      ],
      "Default": "Wait 24 Hours"
    },
    "Wait 24 Hours": {
      "Type": "Wait",
      "Seconds": 86400,
      "Next": "Check Enough Data"
    },
    "Succeed State": {
      "Type": "Succeed"
    }
  }
}
```

but got an error *Expected value of type: Integer, Float insted of String*.
If I replace "$.threshold" with a hard-coded value (like 20), it works, but the value is not dynamic as I want.

The following input should cause the lambda to get to the Succeed State:

```
{
   "country": "japan",
   "threshold": 40
}
```

I know we can replace the Choice step with another Lambda function, but we do not want to do that from cost-effective issues.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use 'NumericGreaterThanPath' operator as per the docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-choice-state.html

Within a Choice Rule, the value of Variable can be compared with another value from the state input by appending 'Path' to name of supported comparison operators.

NumericEqualsPath, NumericGreaterThanPath, NumericGreaterThanEqualsPath, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The comparison operators need to have an integer after ":". It can't be an string.

A workaround is that `"Variable": "$.count"` change to `"Variable": "$.count/$.threshold"` so that you can have `"NumericGreaterThan": 1`. 
In that case, you have count and threshold that define the Choice action.

Let me know if that fixes your problem

Precision: `"Variable": "$.count"` becomes `"Variable": "$.ratio"` 
where `ratio = count/threshold`

Comment: @taras I am facing similar issues and tried `NumericGreaterThanEqualsPath ` but since the output value of the lambda function is in string and it does not compare correctly, details available in the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77786230/how-to-compare-two-input-string-values-which-is-actually-numeric-values-in-aws-s